# Angular 4 server side rendering to serve a fully generated HTML page

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-module

I am starting with Angular4.I am trying to integrate server side rendering for SEO purpose with some [Angular 4 free templates](https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4) which needs to integrated in my actual project later on.Though app is successfully building I am facing below while running the Angular app

```
    > ang_bs@0.0.0 start /Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs
    > ts-node src/server.ts

    listening on http://localhost:4001!
    ERROR { ReferenceError: document is not defined
        at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js:2818:72)
        at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_renderer.ts:166:62)
        at createElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9220:23)
        at createViewNodes (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:320:1)
        at createRootView (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12114:5)
        at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12788:12)
        at ComponentFactory_.create (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9893:46)
        at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3365:29)
        at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts:670:1)
        at /Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts:415:1
    __zone_symbol__currentTask:
    ZoneTask {
        _zone:
        Zone {
            _properties: [Object],
            _parent: [Object],
            _name: 'angular',
            _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
        runCount: 0,
        _zoneDelegates: null,
        _state: 'notScheduled',
        type: 'microTask',
        source: 'Promise.then',
        data: undefined,
        scheduleFn: undefined,
        cancelFn: null,
        callback: [Function],
        invoke: [Function] } }
    Unhandled Promise rejection: document is not defined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: { ReferenceError: document is not defined
        at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js:2818:72)
        at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_renderer.ts:166:62)
        at createElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9220:23)
        at createViewNodes (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:320:1)
        at createRootView (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12114:5)
        at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12788:12)
        at ComponentFactory_.create (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9893:46)
        at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3365:29)
        at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts:670:1)
        at /Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts:415:1
    __zone_symbol__currentTask:
    ZoneTask {
        _zone:
        Zone {
            _properties: {},
            _parent: null,
            _name: '<root>',
            _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
        runCount: 0,
        _zoneDelegates: null,
        _state: 'notScheduled',
        type: 'microTask',
        source: 'Promise.then',
        data: undefined,
        scheduleFn: undefined,
        cancelFn: null,
        callback: [Function],
        invoke: [Function] } } ReferenceError: document is not defined
        at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js:2818:72)
        at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_renderer.ts:166:62)
        at createElement (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9220:23)
        at createViewNodes (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:320:1)
        at createRootView (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12114:5)
        at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12788:12)
        at ComponentFactory_.create (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9893:46)
        at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3365:29)
        at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (/Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts:670:1)
        at /Applications/Workspace/Angular/Ang_Bs/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts:415:1
```

below is my package.json snippet

"prestart": "ng build --prod && ./node_modules/.bin/ngc",

"start": "ts-node src/server.ts"

Any help is really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported @angular/platform-browser to use document object?

```
   import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Injectable()
    export class MyService {
      constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}
    }
```

Else if your using `document.getElementById()`

you need to create an html element as importing

```
   HTMLElement el = document.getElementById()

..
```

Else if your doing dynamic DOM operation, it is better to create a promise to resolve the DOM  to load.